# Grop array in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Australia
            [1] => Brazil
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Brazil
            [1] => Argentina
        )

)
```

i want display it into div in html

```
<b>div</b><br>
    Australia<br>
    Jakarata<br>
<b>div</b><br><br>
<b>div</b><br>
    Brazil<br>
    Argentina<br>
<b>div</b><br>
```

Comment: So where is `Jakarata` supposed to appear from?

Comment: What's a "grop"? A "get away" from a duplicate question word?

Comment: But I think you're looking to use [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loops

Comment: @Fred-ii- Just wanted to ask to same.

Comment: @Daan I'm thinking OP dropped the "u" to read as "group array". Or "crop", but I highly doubt that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
foreach($array as $element){
  echo "<b>div</b><br/>";
  foreach($element as $country){
      echo $country."<br/>";
   }
  echo "<b>div</b><br/>";
}
?>
```

this should work

Answer (score 0):

An other way:

```
foreach($array as $item) {
    vsprintf("<div>\n%s<br/>\n%s</div>", $item);
}
```